# hd param not available on decoding id_token - Google auth

Tags: reactjs, google-signin, google-workspace

I am using 'react-google-login' for google sign in.

```
<GoogleLogin
    clientId="my-google-app-token"
    render={renderProps => (
      <button onClick={renderProps.onClick}>This is my custom Google button</button>
    )}
    buttonText="Login"
    onSuccess={responseGoogle}
    onFailure={responseGoogle}
    hostedDomain={myDomainName.com}
  />
```

I am setting hostedDomain parameter so that the I can send the id_token that is received on successful login to backend for decoding.

The google developer documentation https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth says

> If you want to restrict access to only members of your G Suite domain,
>   verify that the ID token has an hd claim that matches your G Suite
>   domain name.

But the the when decoding token, hd param is not available.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you are using this google login to a specific kind of G-users who are subscribed to your G-suits domain.

In the doc you have referred.

> If you are a G Suite customer, you might also be interested in the hd claim, which indicates the hosted domain of the user. This can be used to restrict access to a resource to only members of certain domains. **The absence of this claim indicates that the user does not belong to a G Suite hosted domain.**

check the bolded test.
hope that answers your question.

Comment: `{accountDomain: undefined
expectedDomain: "myDomainName.com"
reason: "Account domain does not match hosted_domain specified by gapi.auth2.init."
type: "tokenFailed"}`

Comment: When I login, I get this error. I am not sure why accountDomain says undefined

Comment: are you doing this via localhost domain?

Comment: Yes. Through localhost

Comment: Can you try adding http://localhost:port to the authorized urls in nthe G-API you are using?

Comment: I have added http://localhost:3000 in the google developer console _Authorized JavaScript origins
For use with requests from a browser. This is the origin URI of the client application. It can't contain a wildcard (https://*.example.com) or a path (https://example.com/subdir). If you're using a nonstandard port, you must include it in the origin URI._

Comment: It is a gsuite hosted domain, because I can login via Google with that domain name. But when I tried with another gsuite hosted domain it worked